# Memory leaks by passing activity to javascriptinterface?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        webView.loadUrl("https://your_website.com");
    }

    public void doSomeStuff() {
        //do some stuff that requires context or activity
    }

}
```

WebAppInterface:

```
public class WebAppInterface {

    AppCompatActivity a;

    public WebAppInterface(AppCompatActivity a) {
        this.a=a;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void calculate() {
        a.doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Can this cause memory leaks? If yes, what is the easiest way to achieve what I want (to call doSomeStuff from within WebAppInterface)?

Edit 1: Why do I think this can cause memory leaks? Because there is a reference to the activity inside WebAppInterface and maybe this reference is not getting deleted by the garbage collector once the activity gets destroyed.

Edit 2: As I see it, WebView is part of the MainActivity and therefore can't live longer than MainActivity. And WebAppInterface must be also a "member" of WebView and therefore there should be no memory leaks, right?

Answer (score 0):

This specific code won't cause memory leaks, only a cyclic reference (Activity -> WebView -> WebAppInterface -> Activity).

After your activity is destroyed it will no longer be referenced by the OS, but will still be referenced within the cyclic reference.

Lucky for us, the GC is smart and recognize that even though all objects in the cycle reference each other, as a cluster, they are not being referred by classes outside the circle and eventually will be marked for death.